# Finding the cycle length of quadratic residue sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Assume the pseudo-random number generator ([bbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub)) where:

$$
x_{n+1} = x_{n}^2 \pmod{M}
$$

where $M = p \cdot q$, $ \, p$ and $q$ primes that are congruent to $3 \pmod{4}$. Thanks to Euler's theorem there is a closed formula:

$$
x_n = \left(x_0^{2^n \pmod{\lambda(M)} }\right) \pmod{M},
$$

where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

Obviously, since it's a sequence of quadratic residues, the output is going to repeat itself.

The objective is to find the exact period (cycle length) of the generator.

### Attempt:

We must find the smallest $m \neq 1$ that satisfies:

$$
x_m = \left(x_0^{2^m \pmod{\lambda(M)} }\right) \pmod{M} = x_0
$$

but I have no idea how to do that.

Can someone suggest a method for finding such $m$?